# Scrutinizer - PSQL - Access denied with postgres user

Tags: postgresql, psql, scrutinizer

This is my configuration for Scrutinizer instances :

```
build:
dependencies:
    before:
        - psql -c 'CREATE DATABASE db_name WITH OWNER scrutinizer;'
        - psql -c "ALTER ROLE postgres WITH PASSWORD 'postgres'"
        - psql -c 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE "db_name" to postgres'
        - cp .env.example .env
project_setup:
    override:
        - true
environment:
    php:
        version: 7.0.6
    node: 4.0
    variables:
        APP_KEY: 'app_key'
        BUGSNAG_API_KEY: 'test'
tests:
    override:
        -   
            command: vendor/bin/phpunit -v --debug --coverage-clover=my-coverage-file --configuration phpunit.xml
            coverage:
                file: my-coverage-file
                format: php-clover
```

checks:
    php:
        code_rating: true
        duplication: true

but i can not access psql with user postgres, any ideas ?

```
Access denied for user 'postgres'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: That looks like a `mysql` error message. It seems your PHP code is connecting to MySQL rather then Postgres

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ok let me check

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks a lot you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Resolution:

SC can not determine the `.env` or `phpunit.xml` in this case, so i have to specify it in my web Test Case `setup` method:

```
    putenv('DB_DATABASE=db_name');
    putenv('DB_USERNAME=postgres');
    putenv('DB_PASSWORD=postgres');
    putenv('DB_CONNECTION=pgsql');
    putenv('DB_PORT=5432');
```

the most important variable is `DB_CONNECTION`.